# Can I detect unicode string language code?

Tags: python, unicode, internationalization, detection

I'm faced with a situation where I'm reading a string of text and I need to detect the language code (en, de, fr, es, etc).

Is there a simple way to do this in python?

Comment: I have written a [code](https://gist.github.com/ritwikmishra/bd46a4772e720aa5478283acc928b68f) to detect the script. However this will not be able to differentiate languages with same script (like en, fr, es).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to detect language in response to a user action then you could use [google ajax language API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/using_rest_langdetect.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import urllib, urllib2

def detect_language(text,
    userip=None,
    referrer="http://stackoverflow.com/q/4545977/4279",
    api_key=None):        

    query = {'q': text.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(text, unicode) else text}
    if userip: query.update(userip=userip)
    if api_key: query.update(key=api_key)

    url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/detect?v=1.0&%s'%(
        urllib.urlencode(query))

    request = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers=dict(Referer=referrer))
    d = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))

    if d['responseStatus'] != 200 or u'error' in d['responseData']:
        raise IOError(d)

    return d['responseData']['language']

print detect_language("Python - can I detect unicode string language code?")
```

#### Output

```
en
```

#### [Google Translate API v2](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html)

Default limit 100000 characters/day (no more than 5000 at a time).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import urllib, urllib2

from operator import itemgetter

def detect_language_v2(chunks, api_key):
    """
    chunks: either string or sequence of strings

    Return list of corresponding language codes
    """
    if isinstance(chunks, basestring):
        chunks = [chunks] 

    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2'

    data = urllib.urlencode(dict(
        q=[t.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(t, unicode) else t 
           for t in chunks],
        key=api_key,
        target="en"), doseq=1)

    # the request length MUST be < 5000
    if len(data) > 5000:
        raise ValueError("request is too long, see "
            "http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/terms.html")

    #NOTE: use POST to allow more than 2K characters
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data,
        headers={'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'GET'})
    d = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))
    if u'error' in d:
        raise IOError(d)
    return map(itemgetter('detectedSourceLanguage'), d['data']['translations'])
```

Now you could [request detecting a language explicitly](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html#detect-language):

```
def detect_language_v2(chunks, api_key):
    """
    chunks: either string or sequence of strings

    Return list of corresponding language codes
    """
    if isinstance(chunks, basestring):
        chunks = [chunks] 

    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect'

    data = urllib.urlencode(dict(
        q=[t.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(t, unicode) else t
           for t in chunks],
        key=api_key), doseq=True)

    # the request length MUST be < 5000
    if len(data) > 5000:
        raise ValueError("request is too long, see "
            "http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/terms.html")

    #NOTE: use POST to allow more than 2K characters
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data,
        headers={'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'GET'})
    d = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))

    return [sorted(L, key=itemgetter('confidence'))[-1]['language']
            for L in d['data']['detections']]
```

Example:

```
print detect_language_v2(
    ["Python - can I detect unicode string language code?",
     u"матрёшка",
     u"打水"], api_key=open('api_key.txt').read().strip())
```

#### Output

```
[u'en', u'ru', u'zh-CN']
```

Comment: +1: Nice way of leveraging the power of some good, existing tools.

Comment: @ShimonDoodkin: you could try similar services from different providers e.g., [`microsoft-translate.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/9507298).

Answer (score 7):

In my case I only need to determine two languages so I just check the first character:

```
import unicodedata

def is_greek(term):
    return 'GREEK' in unicodedata.name(term.strip()[0])


def is_hebrew(term):
    return 'HEBREW' in unicodedata.name(term.strip()[0])
```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [guess-language](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/guess-language/):

> Attempts to determine the natural language of a selection of Unicode (utf-8) text.

But as the name says, it guesses the language. You can't expect 100% correct results.

**Edit:**

guess-language is unmaintained. But there is a fork (that support python3): [guess_language-spirit](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language)

Answer (score 5):

Look at [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) and [Automatic Language Identification using Python](http://cogscicoder.blogspot.com/2009/03/automatic-language-identification-using.html) for ideas.

I would like to know if a Bayesian filter can get language right but I can't write a proof of concept right now.

Answer (score 3):

[A useful article](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/10/accuracy-and-performance-of-googles.html) here suggests that [this open source named CLD](https://github.com/mikemccand/chromium-compact-language-detector) is the best bet for detecting language in python.

The article shows a comparison of speed and accuracy between 3 solutions :

1. [language-detection](https://code.google.com/archive/p/language-detection/) or its python port [langdetect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect)
2. [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)
3. [Chromium Language Detection (CLD)](https://github.com/mikemccand/chromium-compact-language-detector)

I wasted my time with `langdetect` now I am switching to `CLD` which is 16x faster than `langdetect` and has 98.8% accuracy

Comment: Any idea if langdetect has improved since you answered this question?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Universal Encoding Detector`](http://chardet.feedparser.org/) its a port of `chardet` module from Firefox to Python.

Comment: It's a nice library, but it gives me encoding instead of locale, which I have no use for. still, thanks.

Comment: You can just map encoding to locale.

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez: That is only possible if the language has its own charset. A lot of languages share the same alphabet. Which locale does ascii map to?

Comment: @pafcu, true but on a piece of text you can only detect encoding, not locale, thats system dependent.

Comment: I assume sa125 means language, not locale.

Comment: @pafcu: ASCII was specifically designed for en_US; the "A" does stand for "American".  A better example is windows-1252, which is used for English, German, Spanish, French, Italian, etc.

Comment: @dan04: ASCII was designed for "en_US", but that does not mean that it's not used elsewhere. Just because a text is in ASCII does _not_ mean that it is written in US english.

Comment: @dan04: Here's an example in ASCII that is not English text: `'Jeto ne anglijskij tekst'` (`detect_language_v2()` from  my answer says (incorrectly) that it is *'cs'* (Czech) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545977/python-can-i-detect-unicode-string-language-code/4546813#4546813 ) Actually it is a transliteration of Russian (so google's guess is almost correct).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, nice example.

Answer (score -1):

If you only have a limited number of possible languages, you could use a set of dictionaries (possibly only including the most common words) of each language and then check the words in your input against the dictionaries.