# Simplejson and random key value

Tags: python, python-2.7, simplejson

Here is the value i got from API server

> {"query":{"pages":{"-1":{"ns":0,"title":"spencerx","missing":""}}}}

Let say if i want to get determine if it's not missing word, i will know by looking at "-1" of the return. but when the word exist, it will returning me the following json

> {"query":{"pages":{"1080152":{"pageid":1080152,"ns":0,"title":"spencer"}}}}

which is a random number. may i know how could i detect that's '-1' and determine the word doesn't exist? while i try to print x['query']['pages'] it will just throw all the following behind to me, but i don't know how to detect it's key error. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `print x['query']['pages'].keys()`, which would give you `['-1']` for the first case and `['1080152']` for the second one.

if you just want to check `'-1'` in `x['query']['pages']`:

```
if '-1' in x['query']['pages']:
   # dictionary x['query']['pages'] has '-1' as a key
```

would suffice