# How to know if a website is non-english?

Tags: python, html

I'm doing something like detect website languages. It's about 1k websites so I can't do it 1 by 1. I think to do so I need to get website html code by python and get all the texts, do analyze. Is it correct, has anyone did something like this it would be very helpful :)

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Kindly show your attempts and any errors you might face.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605062/detecting-whether-or-not-text-is-english-in-bulk
this might help

Comment: Do you mean the code, or the content? What about sites that support multiple languages/i18n?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering, I found a way to to it. By listing website's alexa rank and most visitor's country. If it is US or other english speaking country then it's english website.

did it by python.