# Python JSON Google Translator extraction problem

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I am trying to extract the JSON object in python using Simplejson. But I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Translator.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "Translator.py", line 38, in main
    parse_json(trans_text)
  File "Translator.py", line 27, in parse_json
    result = json['translations']['translatedText']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

This is my `JSON` object looks like,

```
{'translations': [{'translatedText': 'fleur'}, {'translatedText': 'voiture'}]}
```

and this is my python piece of code for it.

```
def parse_json(trans_text):   
    json = simplejson.loads(str(trans_text).replace("'", '"'))    
    result = json['translations']['translatedText']
    print result
```

any idea on it?

Comment: where `trans_text` is coming from? You should not need neither `str()` nor `.replace()` calls.

Comment: yah, but Python is not supporting single quotes. Hence I need to replace all with double quotes.

Comment: If your text is in JSON format (as defined by http://json.org) then strings must be already in double quotes. Correct JSON text can contain any Unicode character therefore `str()` will fail on any character that can't be encoded using `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json['translations']` is a list by your definition, so its indices must be integers

to get a list of translations:

```
translations = [x['translatedText'] for x in json['translations']]
```

another way:

```
translations  = map(lambda x: x['translatedText'], json['translations'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`json['translations']` is a list of objects. To extract the `'translatedText'` property, you could use [`itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

print map(itemgetter('translatedText'), json['translations'])
```

See the implementation of [`detect_language_v2()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545977/python-can-i-detect-unicode-string-language-code/4546813#4546813) for another usage example.