# How to detect the language type of a given text via Python?

Tags: python, nlp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - can I detect unicode string language code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545977/python-can-i-detect-unicode-string-language-code)

similar question is [Python - can I detect unicode string language code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4545977/4279)

I had used Google Translate API to detect language type before. The result is perfect, but it's not free now. So I have to find a substition. Any suggestion?

Comment: See the other answers to that question.