# Opening UTF16 URL with urllib in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, urllib, google-translate

I'm trying to use the Google Translate API to translate text that is in Kannada (and hence encoded utf-16) to English. Manually entering my URL, after pluggin in my google api key, https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=key#&q=ಚಿಂಚೋಳಿ&source=kn&target=en, I'm able to get the translation I want.

The problem is, however, that this url is utf16 encoded. When I try to open url using urllib, I get the error message from below. Any advice about how to proceed or an alternative way to proceed would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I believe the problem can be solved by calling urllib.parse.quote_plus(text) where text is the utf16 text, and replacing the utf16 text with the return value from that function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 156, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 469, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 487, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 1283, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 1248, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/http/client.py", line 1061, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/http/client.py", line 1089, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/http/client.py", line 953, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 73-79: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `print(repr(url))` in the original question?

Comment: quote_plus or quote seem to be an option to me.

Comment: look at [how this answer constructs an url from Unicode input](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4546813/4279) i.e., use utf-16 only once when you decode input bytes into Unicode, after that it doesn't matter what the input encoding is.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is, however, that this url is utf16 encoded

UTF-16 doesn't mean what you think it means. It is an encoding of Unicode characters to bytes used internally by the string types of some systems such as the Win32 API. UTF-16 is almost never used on the web because it is not ASCII-compatible.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=key#&q=ಚಿಂಚೋಳಿ&source=kn&target=en
```

This is not a URI - URIs may contain only ASCII characters. It is an [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier), which *can* contain other Unicode characters.

However `urllib` does not support IRIs. There are some Python libraries that do directly support IRI; alternatively you can convert any IRI into a corresponding URI which `urllib` will be happy with. This is done by encoding any non-ASCII characters in the hostname using the IDNA algorithm, and encoding any non-ASCII characters in other parts of the address (including the query parameters) using URL-encoding on the UTF-8 representation of the characters. That gives you this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=key#&q=%E0%B2%9A%E0%B2%BF%E0%B2%82%E0%B2%9A%E0%B3%8B%E0%B2%B3%E0%B2%BF&source=kn&target=en
```

However, the use of `#` here doesn't look right- that's a client-side mechanism for passing in data from the browser, which won't work for server requests.

Usually you'd do something like:

```
baseurl= 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2'
text= u'ಚಿಂಚೋಳಿ'
url= baseurl+'?'+urllib.urlencode(dict(
    source= 'kn', target= 'en',
    q= text.encode('utf-8'),
    key= key
))
```

Comment: there is no need to encode Unicode string in Python 3.3 `urlencode({'q':u'ಚಿಂಚೋಳಿ'})` works just fine.